# Why IGARCH and GARCH (out of six models) with t distribution or GED distribution are optimal when modeling six FX time series?

Tags: time-series, distributions, normal-distribution, arima, garch

I recently performed conditional variance model specification on six different time series (`USDGBP`, `USDJPY`, `USDCAD`, `USDRUB`, `USDAUD`, `USDEUR`). The correct form ARMA have been specified for each of the six series before taking conditional variance tests. The results shown below are results for USDJPY and USDCAD [USDJPY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoGy5.jpg)[image: USDJPY][[image: USDCAD] There are different models I have tried and each of model has been used with normal, $t$, and GED distribution.

What puzzles me a lot is that the information criterion consistently shows that `IGARCH(1,1)` with $t$ distribution and `GARCH(1,1)` with t distribution have the lowest BIC for three different series (`USDGBP`, `USDJPY`, `USDCAD`); And `IGARCH(1,1)` with GED distribution and `GARCH(1,1)` with GED distribution have the lowest BIC for two other different series (`USDEUR`, `USDRUB`); The last series has `GJR` with $t$ distribution as the lowest BIC. (as attached files). And the results are verified by other classmates.

So the results show that `IGARCH` and `GARCH` dominate the whole set of possible models with only $t$ distribution and GED distribution that matters.

But why is that? Is this because `GARCH(1,1)` is simple enough to explain the conditional variance of the time series so that it has lowest BIC? And `IGARCH(1,1)` has $\alpha + \beta = 1$, which well approximate `GARCH(1,1)`? And why only $t$ distribution and GED distribution matters here?

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour]. The site automatically adds a signature block to any of your questions or answers, so we typically leave that off.

Comment: You have only six currency pairs, so effectively six data points, from which you draw conclusions. Out of the six, you find two different GARCH specifications and two different error distributions. I would hesitate to conclude anything much from that. Also, I doubt that any ARMA terms should be used. Currency exchange rates are basically unpredictable, while ARMA patterns generate predictability. That does not square too well. (Currency exchange rates are of course complicated processes, so I would not expect the findings to be easily explainable in a simple way.)

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for your reply! Can you elaborate more on your point "Currency exchange rates are basically unpredictable, while ARMA patterns generate predictability. That does not square too well. "? Because by fitting ARMA processes, I found ARMA form with residuals non-serial correlated.

Comment: @RichardHardy Can you briefly comment on my attempt to explain it? How correct/how wrong are those attempts? And by say "I doubt that any ARMA terms should be used", do you mean that ARMA 00 may be the best form to be performed on those GARCH specifications and error distributions?

Comment: It is possible to find a well-fitting ARMA model for historical data of FX. However, if you try forecasting from that model, you will see that the forecast performs worse than a forecast from a random-walk model. So while the empirical autocorrelations in any given historical time series may suggest that the data generating process can be approximated by an ARMA model, that will be illusory (when we are talking about FX rates, stock prices and the like). And w.r.t. your second comment, yes, I mean keeping the conditional mean model like $FX_t=FX_{t-1}+u_t$ (and $u_t$ is a GARCH process).

Comment: @RichardHardy Just to confirm that, you mean the conditional mean model like AR(1) process (the formula in your last reply), rather than a ARMA(0,0) process?

Comment: That is a special case of AR(1): a random walk (the coefficient on $FX_{t-1}$ is fixed at 1).

Comment: @RichardHardy As you can see here, I specify various conditional variance distributions with various error distributions. But I heard opinion saying that " if I specify ARCH distribution with error distribution being each of the normal distribution, t distribution or GED distribution. I can determine which error distribution is the best. And then I can only specify other GARCH distribution with that determined error distribution, which will makes that list (as in the picture) shorter. Do you agree with that?

Comment: Do you mean, select distribution before selecting the GARCH order? I do not see why this should work.

Comment: @RichardHardy I meant that if I compared the BIC of ARCH-Normal, ARCH-t, ARCH-GED and found out that ARCH-t is the best. Can I continue to compare the BIC of GARCH-t, EGARCH-t, GARCHM-t without considering GARCH-Normal, GARCH-GED, EGARCH-Normal, EGARCH-GED, GARCHM-Normal, GARCHM-GED?

Comment: No, I do not see a reason this should work. Of course, you cannot check all possible models, so you will restrict yourself to some subset, but the particular reasoning here is not convincing.

Comment: @RichardHardy But if I compared the BIC of ARCH-Normal, ARCH-t, ARCH-GED and found out that ARCH-t is the best. Can I conclude that the data modelled has fat-tails and high kurtosis, therefore excluding the choice of normal distribution in other specifications ?

Comment: No, unless you can explain and prove *why* that should work. I cannot prove. In fact, I suspect it should be easy to find some counterexamples. You could simulate some GARCH processes and see for yourself. But even if your examples do not suggest that you cannot do what you wish to, it would still not constitute a proof it is OK to do.